Rest request to HDFC mutual fund giving Forbidden error in C#
I am trying to fetch information of HDFC mutual fund scheme data from its website.
Bellow is Code
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://cms.hdfcfund.com")
                    {
                        MaxTimeout = -1,
                        UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                    };
                    var client = new RestClient(options);
                    var request = new RestRequest("/en/hdfc/api/v2/disclosures/monthfortportfolio", Method.Post);
                    request.AddHeader("referer", "https://www.hdfcfund.com/");
                    request.AddHeader("origin", "https://www.hdfcfund.com/");
                    request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
                    request.AddHeader("accept", "*/*");
                    request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br, zstd");
                    request.AddHeader("priority", "u=1, i");
                    request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
                    request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform", "Windows");
                    request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
                    request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
                    request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-site", "same-site");

                    request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                    if (months.Contains(updateDate.Month))
                    {
                        request.AddParameter("year", updateDate.AddYears(-1).Year);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        request.AddParameter("year", updateDate.Year);
                    }

                    request.AddParameter("type", "monthly");
                    request.AddParameter("month", updateDate.Month);

                    using (TelegramAlerts tl = new TelegramAlerts())
                    {
                        await tl.SendToTelegramLogs("before response");
                    }

                    RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

In localhost it is giving result properly but when I deployed it on server it is giving forbidden error.
Can any one suggest what wrong I am doing in this ?
